# use_existing_column in flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using inheritance with Flask-SQLAlchemy on a class. The thing is that I have column conflicts because in some cases, I have two sub classes that have the same column name. For this I wanted to use the `use_existing_parameter` as suggested in https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/inheritance.html and directly in the error i get in my code "`use_existing_column parameter of mapped_column()`".

But the problem is that db.Column (with `db=SQLAlchemy()` with `from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy`, classic in a flask project) of sqlalchemy does NOT have this parameter.

How to do that then ? Cause I really don't understand how to avoid these problems without having to change the column names (and i dont want that)

Thanks in advance !

EDIT : For those who wonder, the SQLAlchemy class of Flask-SQLAlchemy is equivalent to SQLAlchemy.orm so you can use everything from it, including mapped_column instead of Column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a mapped_column()

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#declarative-table-with-mapped-column

```
class Automobile(Base):

     __tablename__ = 'automobiles'

     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     name = Column(String, nullable=False)


class Truck(Automobile):

     name = mapped_column(String, nullable=False, use_existing_column=True)
```

Comment: Hi there thanks for your reply my problem is that I use Flask-SQLAlchemy so I'm afraid I can't use something else than db.Column. Any idea of how to do it then ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: I'm using flask-sqlalchemy also and it works fine.

Comment: Indeed you were right but it seems really bad documented (I mean Flask-SQLAlchemy) because it took me so long to find the place where it was said that sqlalchemy.orm is equal to the SQLAlchemy() class of the flask version. Thanks for your help then 